# Determining whether an assembly is loaded from a byte array

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

Given an Assembly object, how to determine whether this assembly is loaded by `Assembly.Load(byte[])`?

Currently, I use `Module.FullyQualifiedName`. According to MSDN:

> If the assembly for this module was loaded from a byte array then the FullyQualifiedName for the module will be: <Unknown>.

But apparently the value is depends on language of the system...

Comment: File a documentation bug if that statement isn't true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `bool isFromBytes = module.FullQualifiedName.StartsWith("<")`